# RVIZ *** glibc detected ***

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using Hydro with Ubuntu 12.04 and unable to run rviz. I am getting following error when doing `$ rosrun rviz rviz`:

```
[ INFO] [1405607287.945120631]: rviz version 1.10.16
[ INFO] [1405607287.945243544]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha) 
[ INFO] [1405607288.233226022]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1405607288.233341114]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
*** glibc detected *** /home/asif/ROS_CatkinWS_Hydro/devel/lib/rviz/rviz: corrupted double-linked list: 0x00000000020422a0 ***
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 221: dl_open_worker: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args->nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!
```

I removed rviz using `$ sudo apt-get remove ros-hydro-rviz` and tried to re-install using `$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rviz` and it gave me an error:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-rviz
```

Then I downloaded the source from [github](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/tree/hydro-devel) and managed to install it successfully using `catkin_make` but still getting same  `*** glibc detected ***` error as above.

Any idea how to solve this problem! Thanks in advance.

PS: I found couple of similar questions asked earlier, for example [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/159606/hydro-rviz-crashes-groovy-not-glibc-detected-corrupted-double-linked-list/) and [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/150576/rviz-doesnt-start/) but did not found a solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186947/rviz-***-glibc-detected-***/) by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2014-07-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the answer [in this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/159606/hydro-rviz-crashes-groovy-not-glibc-detected-corrupted-double-linked-list/?answer=193260#post-id-193260) where the error msg looks very similar (as you mentioned).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0